# how can i protect my firebase realtime database with rules using FireSharp ( asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, firebase-realtime-database

i have a website (asp.net core 3) with input fields , and all data entered by the visitors will be saved to firebase child (realtime database)
i'm using FireSharp ( Firebase REST API wrapper for the .NET & Xamarin )

FireSharp work only with authSecret , so my server will bypass my Realtime Database Rules
even if my rules are ;

{
"rules": {
".read": false,
".write": false
}
}

can can i protect my database with security rules ?

is it safe to put the auth secret in my own server ?

[image: Firebase rules]

Answer (score 0):

If FireSharp only allows you to access Firebase Realtime Database by specifying the database secret, then it bypasses your security rules completely and has full read/write access to the entire database.

If you want access in a way to adheres to your security rules, you'll have to find another client for your platform, or use the REST API directly and pass the ID token of a user that is signed in to Firebase Authentication rather than passing the database secret.